# How can I pass additional arguments to a property decorator in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have this simple class with a property that has a [property decorator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Decorators.md#property-decorators) applied to it:

```
class MyClass {
    @collectionMember
    public myProperty: number[];

    // ...
}
```

And the decorator function:

```
function collectionMember(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol): void {
    // ...
}
```

How can I pass *additional* arguments to the decorator function? I tried doing the following with no avail:

```
class MyClass {
    @collectionMember("MyProp")
    public myProperty: number[];

    // ...
}
```

Obviously, this yields the error

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It can be done by using a decorator factory.

The factory, is just a function that receives any parameters you want and returns a function with a decorator signature:

```js
// any parameters, even optional ones!
function collectionMember(a: string, b?: number) {
    // the original decorator
    function actualDecorator(target: Object, property: string | symbol): void {
        // do something with the stuff
        console.log(a);
        console.log(target);
    }

    // return the decorator
    return actualDecorator;
}
```

And then you can use it as you described.

```js
class MyClass {
    @collectionMember('MyProp') // 2nd parameter is not needed for this array
    public myProperty: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to access another property of the class `MyClass` from the `@collectionMember` decorator? Say I have `app` declared inside `MyClass`, can I access `app` from within the decorator?