# How can property decorators be invoked at runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, annotations, decorator

Curious how we would invoke a property decorator at runtime.  For example if we run the following code:

```
    function PropertyDecorator(
        target: Object, // The prototype of the class
        propertyKey: string | symbol // The name of the property
        ) {
        console.log("PropertyDecorator called on: ", target, propertyKey);
    }

    class PDE {
        @PropertyDecorator
        name: string;
    }
```

It will log `PropertyDecorator called on:  PDE {} name`, so the decorator is called when the class loads.  Suppose we want to call it again on an instance of `PDE` like this:

```
const newPDE = PDE();
callDecoratorsOnProperties(newPDE);
```

How is that done?

Comment: You can't rerun the decorators, but there are different solutions to run code depending on what you are trying to do

Comment: As I understand them, decorators get applied as modifications to the class when it is created. If you look at the way a decorator is transpiled, it appears that it doesn't persist beyond class creation. https://babeljs.io/repl/ (turn on legacy decorator plugin via plugins section to see it in action)

Comment: Going through the codebase for https://github.com/typestack/class-validator ... but it's a bit "Involved" so I'm trying to understand how it is that they are invoking the decorators with `validate(instance)` ...

Answer (score 0):

The comments are correct.  The property decorators cannot be invoked at runtime.  They are only design time consructs.  So the logging statement in the example question only runs during class loading and then never does anything ever again.  It's up to the 'load` event to provide additional machinery to the class instance that can be used for the purpose I'm looking at, which in this case is validating the instance.

So what I would have to do is alter the prototype of the class and provide an additional function that can be called to validate the instance of the class that has been annotated.

In case anyone is following along in the same "Thought track" my next question was on [how to pass additional arguments to the decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950923/how-can-i-pass-additional-arguments-to-a-property-decorator-in-typescript).